# How can I share AppStore 1Password Pro on my MacBook?

Tags: mac-appstore, dropbox, password

The information on 1Password regarding using/sharing the application one purchased in AppStore is that it is possible. You are given a rundown on how to install on your other device. But it doesn't work because the menus that are mentioned don't exist in the Mac version.
Originally I bought the 1Password Pro App on my iPhone (7) and would like to synchronise the password information via Dropbox on my MacBook Pro. I never received a licence nor secret code by e-mail. 
Is there someone who had/has this same problem? When replying please keep it simple as I'm not a computer genius

Comment: Mac App Store is different from the Mobile App Store. Contact 1password support.

Comment: Which instructions (link) are you following here? Basically you need to get the application from the Mac App Store and then connect to the same Dropbox as you did from the iOS version.

Answer (score 1):

If your ultimate aim is to have access to 1Password and all your stored passwords, serial numbers, etc on both your iPhone and your Mac, you need to install 1Password on both devices.

Assuming you've done that, you have a number of options, but since you're wanting to use Dropbox then do as follows:

**On your iPhone**

Make sure you have synced your 1Password data to Dropbox. To do this:

1. Launch 1Password on your iPhone
2. Tap on the Settings icon at bottom right
3. Go to Vaults > Primary > Sync Service
4. Tap on Sync with Dropbox
5. Follow the prompts to finish the process

**On your MacBook**

Do as follows:

1. Start from scratch and install 1Password on your MacBook again (i.e. If it's already installed, delete it and then download/install it again)
2. Launch 1Password
3. Now, when it launches the first time you should see a screen similar to the one below:

[image: screen shot of "Used 1Password before?" dialog box]

3. Select the *Sync using Dropbox* option
4. Click on the <kbd>Choose File...</kbd> button
5. Navigate to Dropbox and select the 1Password data file (it'll have either a `.agilekeychain` or `.opvault` file extension)
6. Follow the prompts to finish the process

NOTES:

- As mentioned above there are a number of ways you can sync data between iOS and macOS. If you still have problems, you may want to investigate other options (e.g. WLAN, iCloud, etc).
- The AgileBits [Support Forum](https://discussions.agilebits.com) is actively staffed, so it's a good place to go to seek direct support.